# Do I need Google Play Services for a Specific App

Tags: android, http, accelerometer, battery

I have written an app that monitors accelerometer events for a few months. To minimize the battery usage the app only shows a black screen with the following services:

- Accelerometer events
- HTTP request services to send the data based on accelerometer events (I am using the Google Volley library, is this efficient from battery usage point of view?)

My question is can I disable Google Play Service for these events (and any other services using high battery power)? Is anyway to disable all notifications to minimize the battery usage?
Any other suggestion to minimize the battery usage is welcome.

Comment: It's unclear why you think you need Play Services

Comment: That is my question, for these events and Volley services do I need Google Play Services?

Comment: You already said you have a working app. I know for sure volley does not. I would assume the accelerometer doesn't. You only need Play Services if you want to add Google maps or some other Google service

Answer (score 0):

There are few phones comes without google play services. I believe disabling is not possible. If you try, it may break the phone.

Comment: Not disabling but stopping it. I just did but it restarts automatically. Is there away to stop it completely?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no way stop it completely. It will always restart if you try to stop it